# DialogflowCX sends a "nested flow transition"error after 3 consecutive requests while managing different flows

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have an agent managing eight different flows. Each flow returns to the Default Flow Start Page after processing the user request.

The issue is that after 3 consecutive requests I get the following error message: ***"More than 10 nested flow transitions detected:

> [{ "Step 1": { "Type": "INITIAL_STATE", "InitialState": {
> "MatchedIntent": { "Id": "ee2030ba-164f-4b14-ade3-8760e6dbb91d",
> ..."***.

Then the agent stops working.

Does anybody know what is this issue about and how to deal with it?
How should I manage several flows if they are not allowed to come back to the default flow?

I send a Flow graph screen shot.

Thanks in advance
Claudia

[image: FlowGraph_NestedFlowError]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate your issue and create a flow with a sub-flow **order** **flower**:
[image]

I have set the Transition of the subflow order flower to **Default Start Flow**:
[image]

Upon sending the user query in the simulator, the error message appears:
[image]

To be able to fix this, you can use the **End Flow Page** as **Transition** to jump back to caller flow instead of explicitly defining the parent flow name as target.
[image]

Here’s the final output when you use **End Flow Page**, it can jump back to the parent flow successfully without an error.
[image]